#  Linq To XML with Isolated Storage - Root Element is missing

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml, isolatedstorage

I try to read a Xml file from the isolated Storage with Linq to XML.

My file contains the code above :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lense>
   <days>14</days>
   <date>5/29/2012</date>
   <useToday>True</useToday>
   <dateUseToday />
</lense>
```

I write a query like that:

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
   using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new  IsolatedStorageFileStream("Lenses.xml", FileMode.Open, store))
   {
      var custs = from c in XElement.Load(isoStream).Elements("Lense")c;
   }
}
```

But I have the following error :

> Root Element is missing

I don't know why ? Could you explain me and help me?

---

Thanks for your help!

But when I try the following code, I have the same root element error.

```
var custs = from c in XDocument.Load(isoStream).Elements("Lense")
            select c;
```

---

I use this code to see my xml file store in the isolated storage :

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(store.OpenFile("Lenses.xml", FileMode.Open)))
{
    MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

And the xml file contains only one element :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lense>
   <days>14</days>
   <date>5/29/2012</date>
   <useToday>True</useToday>
   <dateUseToday />
</lense>
```

Thanks for help !

---

I know that I can manipulate my xml document with XmlReader :

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Lenses.xml", FileMode.Open, store))
{
   isoStream.Position = 0;
   XmlReader xmlReader;
   xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(isoStream);
   xmlReader.MoveToContent();
   while (xmlReader.Read())
   {
      switch (xmlReader.NodeType)
      {
         case XmlNodeType.Element:
         {
            if (xmlReader.Name == "date")
            {
               // Code here
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

It works, but I prefer a linq to xml solution if possible.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Upper vs. lower case L (`"Lense"` vs `<lense>`)?

Comment: If it was only a case issue, the query would return no elements, no throw an exception. I think you should try displaying the contents of your XML file from the isolated storage, you might be surprised

Comment: We need to see more of the XML file, that is not the complete file. The error is related to the XML.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a full XML Document to load, try:

```
XDocument.Load(isoStream)
```

Instead of:

```
XElement.Load(isoStream)
```

As suggested, you also need `Elements("lense")` with `lense` in lowercase.

Note that if your file actually contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lense>
   <days>14</days>
   <date>5/29/2012</date>
   <useToday>True</useToday>
   <dateUseToday />
</lense>
<lense>
   <days>14</days>
   <date>5/29/2012</date>
   <useToday>True</useToday>
   <dateUseToday />
</lense>
```

It will fail with a multiple root elements error. Different error, similar problem.